# Truncated e-mail

Tags: sendmail, aix

Have a program that runs on an AIX server. An e-mail is being generated and sent out but is being truncated. The e-mail is about 157KB, 3,349 lines and 193,752 characters at the point of truncating.

I've been digging through the sendmail config but am not seeing anything that would cause this. Any ideas?

Comment: Is a partition nearly full?

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply piping to sendmail, perhaps a single dot on a line by itself terminates the message. Invoke sendmail with the `-i` option to prevent this.

If the situation is different then you need to edit your question to add a lot more detail about how you're sending the email.